# i dont want header and footer to be displayed on login page

Tags: reactjs

```
App.js

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Alerts from './utils/Alerts';
import Header from './utils/header';
import Footer from './utils/footer';
import Add from './pages/Add';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <>
              <ConditionalHeader />
              <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
              <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/Alert" element={<Alerts />} />
              <Route path="/Add" element={<Add />} />
              <ConditionalFooter />
            </>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

function ConditionalHeader() {
  const location = window.location.pathname;
  if (location !== '/') {
    return <Header />;
  }
  return null;
}

function ConditionalFooter() {
  const location = window.location.pathname;
  if (location !== '/') {
    return <Footer />;
  }
  return null;
}

this is my code , when i run this , it doesn't display anything on the webapge
```

i don't want header and footer to be displayed in login page , so i've modified the code
but this doesn't seem to work ,
how do i fix this ,

i tried using useLocation too , but that method seems not to work

the console errors

```
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Route> component:

    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68257:78)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67700:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68332:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68270:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66371:5)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries. logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687 react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
    at invariant (history.ts:491:1)
    at Route (components.tsx:353:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
```

these are errors found in console , even though i've placed Routes under Router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am not 100% sure, but I think the issue is you are not allowed any other component but `<Route />` in the `element={}` prop. So it is throwing an error as the `ConditionalHeader` and `ConditionalFooter` are unexpected.

Instead to make it "conditional" you will probably just need to include the `<Header />` and `<Footer />` components in all the`'./pages/..'` files and then not in the login.

For example:

```js
export default function Alerts() {
    ...
    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
                ...
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

Realise this may not be an ideal solution if you have loads of pages and the `<Login />` is the only screen without a header and footer, so you may want to explore another route.